# Instafeed not display feeds

Tags: wordpress, instagram, feed, instafeedjs

I am using http://instafeedjs.com/ to display Instagram feed in my WordPress site.

I have included this file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});
feed.run();
```

and added into the page `<div id="instafeed"></div>`. But this displays

> ReferenceError: Instafeed is not defined

error in the Firebug, and the feed not displays.

Does anyone know solutions to fix this?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>`? what is this? provide url in `script`,which you used. also, provide, where is `js` file located

Comment: your error occured because of your script doesnt called/called too late.

Comment: yes, I was right. your `in‌​stafeed.min.js` called too late.

Comment: Ohh. So what's the best solutions for this? Can i include `in‌​stafeed.min.js` file in header.php file ?

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrapp your code in some delay function, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var feed = new Instafeed({
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'awesome',
      clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
      });

     feed.run();
   });
</script>
```

You called your `in‌​stafeed.min.js` after your code, thats why you get `Not Defined` error.

Another solution will be to call `in‌​stafeed.min.js` file before your code in `Dom`: in header, in body, up to your code. In this case you can use your code without wrapping in delay functions

Comment: Thanks that's work good. I have included `in‌​stafeed.min.js` file in header and all works good.

Comment: I'm glad helped you